# UISegmentedControl customize by code

Tags: swift, class, subclass, uisegmentedcontrol

I have problem with my UISegmentedControl. I created class of segment:

```
import UIKit

class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    func AwakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let myColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    }
}
```

When i trying change something its without changes. In my main ViewController i marked class file of my UISegmentedControl.

Here is func definition in ViewController:

```
 @IBAction func ShowInterval(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
 }
```

Can you help me please? Thanks you so much!

Comment: It's seems to unclear. But I think your problem is a customization of appearance! Right? If so, you shouldn't create a class to it.

Comment: Did you try to print some text to see if the program enters this class?

Comment: I want customize my segmentcontrol by code (for example delete border or change radius). When i print text in subclass it printed as well :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple doc:

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized

Try this:

```
func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let myColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
}
```

Comment: Works! God bless you!